# Why am I getting name 'request' is not defined?

Tags: python, django

I'm following a Django tutorial and have reached the point of using `return render`and currently my views.py looks like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def construction_view(*args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("<h1> This site is currently being constructed. Please check back later </h1>")

def home_view(*args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "home.html", {})
```

I am getting an error whien trying to go to my home page:

```
views.py", line 9, in home_view
    return render(request, "home.html", {})
NameError: name 'request' is not defined
```

Not sure what is causing this as according to Django docs request is part of render which is imported above.

Comment: Where do you define `request`?

Comment: Willems answer is enough to understand the issue but besides that, I suggest you use an advanced editor like Pycharm or VSCode or any other with enough extensions so you get warned for this kind of mistake since the request is completely missing inside your view function. Please note that Django is just python, so if it says the request is always a part of the views, it is the first argument provided to the view function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`request` is always the first parameter of any view. In your view, your function only has `*args` and `**kwargs`, so `request` will be the first item in the `args`. It is better to make the `request` parameter explicit and work with:

```
#        request ↓
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, "home.html", {})
```

Since you likely only use this view for URL patterns without URL patterns, you can probably omit the `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
#                  ↓ omit *args and **kwargs
def home_view(request):
    return render(request, "home.html", {})
```